# How would I disallow special characters in usernames?

Tags: forms, users

By default, Drupal 9 allows usernames to have spaces, periods(.), hyphens(-), apostrophes('), underscores(_) and @ symbols.

How would I **disallow** spaces, periods, apostrophes and @ symbols?

Comment: Maybe [User Name Validation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/username_validation) or [User Restrictions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions) can help.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Looks like the User Name Validation module does exactly what I need.

Comment: Great.  If it works for you, feel free to answer your own question with the details of how you configured the module.

Answer (score 2):

I used the [Username Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/username_validation) module suggested by Patrick Kenny in [his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/309621/how-would-i-disallow-special-characters-in-usernames#comment393075_309621). The *Blacklist characters* field shown by the module on /admin/config/people/user-name-validation did the trick.

Comment: There are also a LOT of other questions on here that ask the same or similar question. See the "Related" block to the right ->

Comment: All of those questions are outdated or have nothing to do with the question of disallowing characters. I did search the website first before posting. Now admittedly, I didn't search "validation" when googling, which is probably why I didn't find the module that solved my problem.